# (Angular) Listen to validation changes from reactive child form groups

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

In my main component I render a form whose form groups sit in child components. The main component initializes with some defaults and the child components initialize themselves with some validators and other logic.

Now I was thinking that with a `valueChanges` subscription on the main form the main component gets the changes in the child form groups somehow automatically. But there's a connecting piece missing as the form is always "valid" even when there are validation errors in the child form groups.

What did I miss?

main.component.ts:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeFormGroup();
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(
      result => console.log(this.form.valid); // always outputs true!?
    );
  });
}

private initializeFormGroup(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    child1: this.formBuilder.group({}),
    child2: this.formBuilder.group({})
  });
}
```

main.component.html:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <child1></child1>
  <child2></child2>
</form>
```

child1.component.ts:

```js
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initializeFormGroup();
  this.checkStuffAndAddValidators();
}


get formArray(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('array') as FormArray;
}

private initializeFormGroup(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    array: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}

private checkStuffAndAddValidators(): any {
    const newGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      inputA: ['', [Validators.required]],
      inputB: ['']
    });

    if (this.someConditionIsTrue) {
      newGroup
        .get('inputB')
        .setValidators([MyValidator]);
      newGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
    }

    this.array.push(newGroup);
  });
}
```

child1.component.html:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="array" *ngFor="let control of formArray.controls; let i = index">
  <ng-container formGroupName="{{ i }}">
    <input name="inputA" formControlName="inputA" />
    <input name="inputB" formControlName="inputB" />
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

child2.component.ts:

```js
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initializeFormGroup();
}

get formArray(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('array') as FormArray;
}

addInput() {
  if (!this.formArray.valid) {
    return;
  }
  this.formArray.push(this.createNewFormGroup());
}

removeInput(index: number) {
  this.formArray.removeAt(index);
}

private initializeFormGroup(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    array: this.formBuilder.array([this.createNewFormGroup()])
  });
}

private createNewFromGroup(): FormGroup {
return this.formBuilder.group({
  inputA: ['', [Validators.required]],
  inputB: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
```

child2.component.html:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="array" *ngFor="let control of formArray.controls; let i = index">
  <ng-container formGroupName="{{ i }}">
    <input name="inputA" formControlName="inputA" />
    <a (click)="removeInput(i)">del</a>
    <a (click)="addInput()">add</a>
    <input name="inputB" formControlName="inputB" />
    <a (click)="removeInput(i)">del</a>
    <a (click)="addInput()">add</a>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the main component where you listen to changes formBuilder does not have any validations. Only in child components they are validated. If you listen changes in child components you might see form is not always valid. 
You can listen in child components and emit them to the main component using an `EventEmitter` or you can add validations to the form instance in main component.

*To make sure you can debug and check whether there are any validations in your form in main.component*

Answer (score 0):

The childs have their own forms and are not linked to the parent form os you need to pass the formgroups to the child components:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <child1 [form]="form.get('child1')></child1>
  <child2 [form]="form.get('child2')></child2>
</form>
```